# How to prevent user from voting twice?

Tags: php, mysql

(sorry English not strongsuit) i'm currently following this tutorial system. https://codeshack.io/poll-voting-system-php-mysql/

What i'd like to is prevent users from voting twice, and im not exactly sure how to do this, I have done some googling and ive read about cookies, but unsure how to make it work with this code.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'functions.php';
// Connect to MySQL
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();
// If the GET request "id" exists (poll id)...
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    if(isset($_SESSION['voted'],$_SESSION['voted'][(string)$_GET['id']])){
        die('Your vote is already considered.');
    }

    $_SESSION['voted'][(string)$_GET['id']] = true; // or you might want to set this on successful update of update query
    // MySQL query that selects the poll records by the GET request "id"
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM polls WHERE id = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]);
    // Fetch the record
    $poll = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Check if the poll record exists with the id specified
    if ($poll) {
        // MySQL query that selects all the poll answers
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM poll_answers WHERE poll_id = ?');
        $stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]);
        // Fetch all the poll anwsers
        $poll_answers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // If the user clicked the "Vote" button...
        if (isset($_POST['poll_answer'])) {
            // Update and increase the vote for the answer the user voted for
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE poll_answers SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE id = ?');
            $stmt->execute([$_POST['poll_answer']]);
            // Redirect user to the result page
            header ('Location: result.php?id=' . $_GET['id']);
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        die ('Poll with that ID does not exist.');
    }
} else {
    die ('No poll ID specified.');
}
?>
<?=template_header('Poll Vote')?>

<div class="content poll-vote">
    <h2><?=$poll['title']?></h2>
    <p><?=$poll['des']?></p>
    <form action="vote.php?id=<?=$_GET['id']?>" method="post">
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($poll_answers); $i++): ?>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="poll_answer" value="<?=$poll_answers[$i]['id']?>"<?=$i == 0 ? ' checked' : ''?>>
            <?=$poll_answers[$i]['title']?>
        </label>
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Vote">
            <a href="result.php?id=<?=$poll['id']?>">View Result</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<?=template_footer()?>
```

Comment: If you are determined to prevent all duplicate voting then the short answer to your question is: authentication + validation. Cookies is not a good solution unless you assume that each user only has access to one browser on one device, and none of the users know how to clear cookies or start an incognito session. But of course, in 2020 these are not realistic assumptions.

Comment: Of course even then it may not prevent people from creating multiple user accounts in order to vote multiple times, but it will make it more complicated and tedious, so will deter some. There is more that could be done, potentially. But you didn't really say how significant the vote is - e.g. is it just some vox pop poll on a blog site, or a serious survey, or a genuine democratic process?? The precautions you take and the time, effort and money you expend on fraud prevention will necessarily be proportionate to the importance of the result and the importance of the integrity of the data.

Comment: Hi there, sorry, This vote isn't really serious. i'm just looking for the most basic, simple solution to having users only vote once, if they clear their cookies and revote for example thats fine.

Comment: i dont need very good security for this example, basically.

Comment: Right well for just a very casual system then cookies would be fine

Comment: *"i dont need very good security for this example"* - You should. Btw, you can check if a user has voted more than once if you check if they have by counting the vote column with a boolean check with a SELECT query. @bob011 Just handle it with an `if/else`. I wouldn't rely solely on JS to do this though, serverside should also be used.

Comment: @ADyson yes this is a very casual system with no real world use case.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner Hi there, thankyou for that. This has no real world use case. Could you show me some example code with your explanation? i appreciate the response.

Comment: I was hoping to make it work like this does. https://votingking.herokuapp.com/guest/polls thankyou

Answer (score 2):

2 things to follow in this:

- Disable the vote button as soon as it is clicked to ensure double clicking is not done on it and make your ajax request.
- Second, you also need to mark a user as voting done for a particular poll to avoid re- voting. So before updating `poll_answers` with votes, you will have to check from your DB table as well as to whether the user has already voted. If yes, reject, else accept the vote.

Your user storage of poll votes table to judge store a user's vote would look like:

```
id | user_id | poll_id | created_at
```

Before updating `poll_answers`, if you see an entry in this table for a user and for a poll in context, reject the vote, else accept it and make an entry in this table. This actually represents *many-to-many relationship* between `users` and `polls`.

**Important Note:** A user has to be registered to vote, else there is no way to ensure an anonymous user can't vote twice. Session cookies can be played with too since it comes from client side in return. So, even sessions as an option is ruled out.

---

On your request, disabling of button code would look like(assuming you are using jquery):

```
$('#make_vote').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    $.ajax({
      //  all params,
      success : function(response){
          // your code
          $('#make_vote').removeAttr('disabled');  
      }
    });
});
```

---

Since you want to achieve this using sessions, **although not recommended**, it would look like:

- Add `session_start()` at the top of all PHP files, excluding your `functions.php`(which seems to have only helper functions).
- Now, you current snippet would look like below:

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'functions.php';
// Connect to MySQL
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();
// If the GET request "id" exists (poll id)...
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    if(!isset($_SESSION['voted'],$_SESSION['voted'][(string)$_GET['id']])){
        //die('Your vote is already considered.');
    if(!isset($_SESSION['voted'])) $_SESSION['voted'] = array();
    $_SESSION['voted'][(string)$_GET['id']] = true; // or you might want to set this on successful update of update query
    // MySQL query that selects the poll records by the GET request "id"
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM polls WHERE id = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]);
    // Fetch the record
    $poll = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Check if the poll record exists with the id specified
    if ($poll) {
        // MySQL query that selects all the poll answers
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM poll_answers WHERE poll_id = ?');
        $stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]);
        // Fetch all the poll anwsers
        $poll_answers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // If the user clicked the "Vote" button...
        if (isset($_POST['poll_answer'])) {
            // Update and increase the vote for the answer the user voted for
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE poll_answers SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE id = ?');
            $stmt->execute([$_POST['poll_answer']]);
            // Redirect user to the result page
            header ('Location: result.php?id=' . $_GET['id']);
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        die ('Poll with that ID does not exist.');
    }}
} else {
    die ('No poll ID specified.');
}
?>
```

---

**Note:** As a more robust security and to avoid same user creating multiple accounts, you can block the IP address to create accounts after a certain threshold.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216948/discussion-on-answer-by-vivek-23-how-to-prevent-user-from-voting-twice).